# How to use master page UI version 16 on publishing site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, publishing-site, 2016

I created a new publishing site in 2016. Then I went to Design Manager and converted an HTML page to Master Page UI version 16. That new master page is checked in and published.

Now when I go to `Site Settings --> Master Page` I do not see my new master page in the drop down list. I then changed its UI version to 15 and it started appearing.

My question is how can I use new UI version 16 master page on publishing site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to. The UI version did not change between SharePoint 2013 and 2016 or SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online. Continue using the v15 UI as you would have with 2013.